# Colour each type differently in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I discovered that we can edit the settings.json in vscode to customise the colours we use: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/colorization-cpp

For example by adding in the `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"` the following block

```
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "entity.name.type",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#7955c2",
                        "fontStyle": "italic bold underline"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

All the name types will be light purple (std::vector, double etc)

**Is it possible to colour specific types differently?** For example, I have a user-defined object called "network" and it would help me a lot to spot it accross the code if it was in a specific colour of my choice.

It seems possible but reading the documentation I really don't understand how to make it happen...

Comment: use the extension **Highlight**

Comment: This is a nice extension I did not know of, thanks! However, it seems to change the colour at every occurrence even in comments or strings whereas I wish to only colour the object "network" for example.

Comment: the extension does not do any parsing, it just uses regex search, and how often do you have such false positives compared to writing your own extension that does parsing and decorating